# Using Parse Dashboard with xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services

I am learning how to use Parse Dashboard with AWS Amazon Server. I have followed the instructions precisely but the xcode doesn't `saveInBackground` - nothing appears in the Parse Dashboard and the error is this:

> 2016-11-20 19:58:21.223 ParseStarterProject-Swift[2902:294330]
>   [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0) Optional(Error
>   Domain=Parse Code=0 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0})
>   LINK TO THE FULL LOG: http://dropmefiles.com/fXvRL

Here's my delegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "myappid"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "mymasterkey"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://*****-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com/parse"
    })

    Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)
```

What can I try to solve the issue?
 Thanks

Comment: try enabling bit code ?

Comment: Thanks. I can't find enabling option in xcode 8. Where should I look?

Comment: I added a ling to the full log file http://dropmefiles.com/fXvRL

Comment: how did you integrate it? did you use cocoapods? please paste your pods file if you use cocoapods.

Comment: I used a Parse Starter Project available on the internet. It builds just fine. I added the server address as per the instruction. Here's the project http://dropmefiles.com/fDRrp

Comment: please post some code, I am getting stuck with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that "Myappid" and "Masterkey" were not generic as the instruction said they would be. They were unique from the beginning and I found them in server.js file.

Comment: hello Anton, how can I locate the file server.js

Comment: got it.. 
follow the below links to get you appId and masterkey
[link](http://iosprogramtips.blogspot.ug/2017/01/parse-service-on-aws.html)

you will have to log into your instance first
mac os- use the terminal to log into your instance 
windows -- use putty to access you instance

open file server.js in location ~/app/parse/htdocs  run command (vim server.js)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the correct applicationId and clientKey. They're unique. Go

Answer (score 0):

first you should connect to your server with putty and follow this directory : apps-->parse-->htdocs-->server.js
in server.js file you can see "Myappid" and "Masterkey"